# Boost multi_array range compilation

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

A range can be used to slice a Boost Multidimensional array (multi_array). According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views) there are several ways of defining a range, however not all of them will compile. I'm using GCC 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 11.04.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main() {
    typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
    range a_range;   

    // indices i where 3 <= i

    // Does compile
    a_range = range().start(3);

    // Does not compile
    a_range = 3 <= range();
    a_range = 2 < range();

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler output is:

```
ma.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ma.cpp:9:26: error: no match for ‘operator<=’ in ‘3 <= boost::detail::multi_array::index_range<long int, long unsigned int>()’
ma.cpp:10:25: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘2 < boost::detail::multi_array::index_range<long int, long unsigned int>()’
```

Any idea how I can compile this, or what is missing?

Comment: have you tried explicitly injecting the entire namespace (i.e. `using boost::deail::multi_array`)? This is where the operators appear to be defined, however maybe with your compiler ADL is failing (ideone for example compiles the above).

Comment: tried `using namespace boost::detail::multi_array` and I still get the error...

Comment: `dpgk` says version 1.42.0. Can't see any relevant [tickets](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost) or anything in the [changelog](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/unordered/changes.html).

Comment: Strange, have just ssh'ed into another machine and it compiles there. Currently checking what's different on there.

Comment: Other machine has Boost 1.33.0 and GCC 4.1.2.

Comment: btw. 1.42. is not certified with 4.5.2 - so there could be some issues there, only 1.46 is certified with 4.5.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator<` and `operator<=` being invoked here are templates; consequently, the value supplied to said operators for the `Index` argument must be the exact same type as the `Index` template parameter of the range being supplied.

The `boost::multi_array_types::index_range::index` type ultimately boils down to a typedef for `std::ptrdiff_t`; given that you're supplying `int` literals, clearly for your platform/configuration, `std::ptrdiff_t` is a typedef for some type other than `int` (according to your error messages it's `long`).

The portable fix is to coerce your literals to the proper type:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::multi_array_types::index_range range;
    typedef range::index index;

    range a_range;
    a_range = index(3) <= range();
    a_range = index(2) < range();

    index i(1);
    a_range = i <= range();
}
```